# OSMdroid: zoomToBoundingBox zooms to wrong bounding box

Tags: java, android, zooming, osmdroid, bounding-box

**PROBLEM:**

I have a bounding box {N:53.2219112; E:-6.1409208; S:53.1953286; W:-6.1784236} which I wish to focus on.

I call `MapView.zoomToBoundingBox` on that bounding box and for some reason it is zooms/centers on {N:54.9918; E:-8.3993; S:54.9651; W:-8.4716} (roughly, I have estimated this from looking and the displayed area on OpenStreetMap.org).

The strange thing is, when I call `MapView.getBoundingBox`, I get {N:78.34941069014627; E:28.125; S:7.01366792756663; W:-50.625}, which is nothing to do with anything.

**TO CONSIDER:**

1)My MapView only takes up part of the screen - just the top, as seen below, so perhaps the correct view dimensions are not properly being calculated?

2)When I manually zoom and center on the `boundingBox.getCenterWithDateLine()`, the view centers on the center of the bounding box - so the input bounding box is correct.

3)I am using my own 'ExtendedMapView' class which extends MapView, as a way of keeping all MapView's functionality in one place, I cant imagine this is causing the problem, but it's worth noting.

4) I am calling zoomToBoundingBox in onLayout as suggested in this thread: https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid/issues/236

5) Im using OSMdroid 6.0.1

[image]

**CODE:**

Called in ExtendedMapView:

```
 @Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

         if(boundingBox != null){
             zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, true);
             //output: N:53.2219112; E:-6.1409208; S:53.1953286; W:-6.1784236
             Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "Required BB: "+boundingBox.toString());

             //output: N:78.34941069014627; E:28.125; S:7.01366792756663; W:-50.625
             Log.d(Constants.SkiCompanionDebug, "Actual BB: "+getBoundingBox().toString());
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a couple of days fooling around, I've found a solution. There's a bug with `zoomToBoundingBox` when you set animate to TRUE. I fixed the problem by setting animate to FALSE, and calling `invalidate()` afterwards.

```
@Override
    protected void onLayout(boolean changed, int l, int t, int r, int b) {
        super.onLayout(changed, l, t, r, b);

         if(boundingBox != null){
             zoomToBoundingBox(boundingBox, false);
             invalidate();
         }
    }
```